# How to show SQL reports in a web application without Reportviewer control in asp.net

Tags: crystal-reports, controls, reporting, reportviewer, report

I want to know if there is any way to show reports without reportviewer control...
My reports are deployed on the report server. Now I want to show these reports in a web application. Please let me know if there's any other way to show reports. I do not want to use report viewer control.

Answer (score 0):

using code all reports can be "exported" to all supported formats like pdf, wrod, excel etc. By export i mean as you show the reports in report viewer and click the export button on the viewer Then you can show  the genereted with somekind of viewer for that format.
Best Regards,
Iordan
P.S. You will need to use the report Viewer to achive this but the use will be internal and the user won't see the report viewer as visualization control. There is no way to show report without the use of report viewer control